# Convergence power iteration

Tags: convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know why one can use the difference of the steps in a power iteration (to find the dominant eigenvector) to find the point when we have converged.

Let b_k be the vector in every step of the iteration. Then everyone uses $|b_k-b_{k-1}|<eps$ to stop the iteration. This looks like that $|b_k-b_{k-1}|$ is an upper bound on the true error $|b_k - x|$ (where $x$ is the dominant eigenvector). But why is that so?

Comment: Frame challenge: it's not.  The error decreases geometrically, by a factor of $|y/x|$ (where $y$ is the second dominant eigenvalue).  So (once the iteration starts converging), $|b_{k+1} - b| \leq |y/x|\,|b_k -b|$.  But this does not mean that $|b_{k+1} - b_k|$ is an upper bound on $|b_{k+1} - b|$  In fact, one can manipulate this to show $$|b_{k+1} - b| < \frac{1}{1-|y/x|} |b_{k+1} - b_k|\text{.}$$  If $|y|\ll|x|$, then the equivalence you describe is almost true.  If $|y|$ is almost $|x|$, then $|b_{k+1} - b|$ can be many times larger than $|b_{k+1} - b_k|$.

Comment: Ahh ok. Can you give me a hint or show me how you do the manipulation to get the formula in the middle?

Comment: This is normal triangle inequality stuff...  Start with $|b_{k+1} - b_k| = |b_{k+1} - b + b - b_k|$ and continue in the usual way.  You'll probably use the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) along the way.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot